# Sequelize findOrCreate insert new row but return object with primary key undefined

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) in one small nodejs project, working with mysql database.

With findOrCreate, I can find existing objects and insert new objects, but when the new object was create and return, the primary key was 'undefined'.

#### definition

```
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        var Student = sequelize.define('Student', {
        id : {
            type : DataTypes.BIGINT,
            primaryKey : true
        },
        wxid : DataTypes.STRING,
        client : DataTypes.STRING,
        nick : DataTypes.STRING,

        wallet : {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0},
        mcount : {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0},
        qcount : {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0},

        status : {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0},
        premium_type : {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0},
        createtime : DataTypes.DATE,
        lastqtime : DataTypes.DATE,
        lastmtime : DataTypes.DATE

        }, {
        freezeTableName : true,
        timestamps : false,
        tableName : 'student_student',
        associate: function(models) {
            Student.hasMany(models.Question, {as:'questions', foreignKey: 'student_id'});
        }
        });

        return Student;
    };
```

#### findOrCreate

```
    db.Student.findOrCreate( { wxid : info.uid },
            {
                client: client_name,
                createtime: new Date(),
                lastmtime: new Date()
            }).success(
            function(stu, created) {
                if (!stu) {
                console.log('Stu[' + info.uid + '] not found.'.red);
                } else {
                if (created) {
                    stu.created = true;
                    console.log(stu.values);    
                    //// Here, stu.id is 'undefined'

                }
                }
            });
```

logs:

```
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32] { id: undefined,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   wxid: 'o6ssct7SHGXN1zlyD6vvfk3TMr68',
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   client: 'wxcs',
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   nick: undefined,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   wallet: 0,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   mcount: 0,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   qcount: 0,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   status: 0,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   premium_type: 0,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   createtime: Fri Jan 10 2014 21:54:32 GMT+0800 (CST),
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   lastqtime: undefined,
    [app-0 (out) 2014-01-10T21:54:32]   lastmtime: Fri Jan 10 2014 21:54:32 GMT+0800 (CST) }
```

But when I look into database, I find the row was inserted correctly.

#### How can I findOrCreate with id set?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Add `autoIncrement: true` to id field, fixing the problem.

Comment: This also fixed this problem for me, and my models were letting Sequelize infer default identifier behaviour (my code had no `id:{...}` specified so I had to add the whole `{ type : DataTypes.BIGINT, primaryKey : true, autoIncrement: true }`).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm here a bit late but you can also declare a default beforeCreate function that will help you with this problem.

E.g. I use shortid as a primary key generator so my [beforeCreate hook](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/) looks like this:

```
define: {
  hooks: {
    beforeCreate: function(o) {
      if (!o.id) o.id = shortid.generate();
    }
  }
}
```